# Using Engineering symbols (*.svg) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

QGIS looks straight forward except for the symbols or icons.

I have created SVG symbols and when I place my pointer to the obvious blank areas in the symbol library a pop-up says that my symbol is there, yet nothing shows in the icon library.

I insert the "ghost" svg into the map and Nothing shows on the map.

Can anyone tell me how to get an SVG file to work in QGIS?

Comment: The accepted answer at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/is-there-a-svg-symbol-library-for-qgis) has a link to a blog post describing the process. What are you creating your SVG symbols in? I note from [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19823/what-version-of-svg-should-i-be-saving-my-images-with-for-qgis-any-particular-o) that Illustrator may not play nice with the format. If neither of those help, you might to a search here on 'qgis svg' and see if any of the other questions/answers might.

Answer (score 16):

Here are points in the table of contents:

[image]

Here's what my SVG that I downloaded from some website looks like to Windows Explorer in my downloads folder:

[image]

And what it looks like in IE:

[image]

Now double-click your point layer to open the layer properties

- choose the Simple Marker
- then from the 'symbol layer type' drop-down in the upper-right, choose "SVG"

[image]

Now choose the little ellipse (browse button) below the SVG Groups panel, and navigate to your SVG you want to use as the symbol:

[image]

Now you're SVG is set as the symbol for your points, and you can adjust the size, etc:

[image]

And here's the result on the map:

[image]

Comment: Just note you can also add more SVG search paths in the Settings -> Options dialog so they will show up in the User Symbols section.

Answer (score -3):

Once you had created the symbol using svg. Create the qml for same symbol and keep along with the shape file. next time whenever you load the same shape file it will take the symbology itself .